# How to sum of function value from related table?

Tags: php, laravel, function, eloquent, sum

I have two Classes: `Share` and related `EquityGrant`

I have this this math function in `EquityGrant`

```
public function share() //relationship
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Share::class, 'share_id');
}
public function capitalCommitted() //my math function
{
    return $this->share_price * $this->shares_amount;
}
```

But now I need to return in my `Share` class sum of `capitalCommitted()` function and here I'm stuck.

My `Share` class:

```
public function grants() //relationship
{
    return $this->hasMany(EquityGrant::class);
}
public function totalIssued() //sum, works good
{
    return $this->grants->sum('shares_amount');
}
public function totalCommitted() //Stuck here
{
    //need help here, Must be like this: array_sum($this->grants->capitalCommitted());
}
```

Comment: how about : public function totalCommitted() 
{
    return $this->grants->sum(DB::raw('share_price * shares_amount'));
}

Comment: returns me 0 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
public function getCapitalCommittedAttribute()
{
    return $this->share_price * $this->shares_amount;
}

public function totalCommitted()
{
    return $this->grants->sum('capitalCommitted');
}
```